# Remove View All menu link only for specific categories RWD theme 1.9

Tags: menu, rwd, renderer

How do I remove view all for one specific category only? These categories do not have children which I think is the problem.

I tried editing renderer.phtml at line 62 with this if statement but it still shows for my category id 3.

```
if ($_catid = $this->getCategoryid('3')) {}
                            else {
        if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
            $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
            $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'">';                      
            $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
            $html .=             $this->__('View All')/* . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()))*/;
            $html .=         '</a>';
            $html .=     '</li>';
            $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
            $html .= '</ul>';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the menu has no idea about the category id. It is simply a node tree. What you could do is take the value of `$child->getId()` and extract the id from it. This id value should look something like `category-node-12` where 12 is the category id.

Though I would maybe suggest that though this would be a fairly "easy" change it is not that flexible and you should really look into how the menu is built.

Another possible idea is to use the event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` and unset the children for your desired category here.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to hide the view all under your second category only. You know the class for the second list item is `nav-2` and all view all's have the class `view-all`. So to hide the view all for second category only you would add this to your css file:

```
.nav-2 .view-all {
   display:none;
}
```